# "HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized" when querying youtube api for playlist with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, urllib, http-error

I try to write a simple python3 script that gets some playlist informations via the youtube API. However I always get a 401 Error whereas it works perfectly when I enter the request string in a browser or making a request with w-get. I'm relatively new to python and I guess I'm missing some important point here.

This is my script. Of course I actually use a real API-Key.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode


api_key = "myApiKey"

playlist_id = input('Enter playlist id: ')
output_file = input('Enter name of output file (default is playlist id')

if output_file == '':
    output_file = playlist_id

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems'

params = {'part': 'snippet',
          'playlistId': playlist_id,
          'key': api_key,
          'fields': 'items/snippet(title,description,position,resourceId/videoId),nextPageToken,pageInfo/totalResults',
          'maxResults': 50,
          'pageToken': '', }

data = urlencode(params)

request = Request(url, data.encode('utf-8'))
response = urlopen(request)
content = response.read()

print(content)
```

Unfortunately it rises a error at `response = urlopen(request)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gpd-helper.py", line 35, in <module>
  response = urlopen(request)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 461, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 571, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 499, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I looked up the documentation but couldn't find any hint. According to the docs other authentication than the api key is not required for listing a public playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving deeper into the docs of python and google I found the solution to my problem.

Pythons [Request object automatically creates a POST  request](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) when the data parameter is given  but the [youtube api expects GET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#) (with post  params)

The Solution is to ether supply the GET argument for the method parameter in python 3.4

```
request = Request(url, data.encode('utf-8'), method='GET')
```

or concatenate the url with the urlencoded post data

```
request = Request(url + '?' + data)
```